# JUnit4 NullPointerException in SubClass Test, overriden method

Tags: java, junit, junit4

when I m trying to test a subclass that has a constructor with one object parameter I found problems

```
public SigFX(final RepRow row) {
    super(row);
    fx = (FX) getTrade().getProduct();
}

@Override
public Object getLcyPdo4Amt() {
    return 0;
}
```

I run the test

```
public class SigFXTest {

    private static final Object RepRowMock = null;
    final RepRow r = new ReportRow(RepRowMock);
    final SigFX s = new SigFX(r);

    @Test
    public void getLcyPdo4AmtTest() {           
        assertEquals(0, s.getLcyPdo4Amt());
    }    
}
```

so it finished with 
java.lang.NullPointerException in: `fx = (FX) getTrade().getProduct();`

Comment: thank you, but in terms of testing I am thinking to implement an exception

@Test(expected= NullPointerException.class)

I am not sure this is the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When super(row) while that execute the super class constructor so, for that you need to mock the base class constructor by following below link.

[Mock the based class constructor](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Suppress-Unwanted-Behavior)